# How to do multitasking in php

Tags: php, xml, multitasking

I have a XML parser in php which reads an XML file and inserts the contents to database. This does it for a single file. But i have hundreds of files, and hundreds more will be added daily.

1. So how should i do multi tasking in php so that i can parallel process more than 1 file.
2. How to do it more efficiently the multi tasking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pcntl_fork()`, this is the "classic" UNIX `fork()` method. Note this only works on UNIX/Linux systems and the the CGI/CLI SAPI.
AFAIK there is no `vfork()` in PHP, so it's not very memory efficient.

There are no threads in PHP. The lack of proper multi-processing is probably the biggest handicap of the language.

[I wrote a little guide](http://arp242.net/weblog/Online_Unreal_Tournament_server_browser_with_pcntl_fork.php%20%22I%20write%20a%20little%20guide) on using `pcntl_fork()` some time ago, you can use it as a starting point if you wish. There are more out there, use Google.

Or, you can just start your script multiple times in the background... Depending on your script, this may be easier ...

Comment: The forking info here is very useful, but I think the last part is the best advice for your case. If you're on a unix, check out xargs. It's amazing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Comment: Your answer says that it may be simpler to start the script multiple times than to manage multiple processes with php code. My comment is that it probably IS easier, especially if xargs is available on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcntl.php - there are a lot of examples in comments

Answer (score 0):

you can use php gearman for multitasking It provides a distributed application framework for work with multiple machines or processes? It allows applications to complete tasks in parallel, to load balance processing, and to call functions between languages. The framework can be used in a variety of applications. Gearman is multi-threaded and is known to be able to carry out 50 thousand jobs per-second.
just visit http://gearman.org/download